# How python resolves private(double underscore) methods inside a class?

Tags: python, cpython, python-internals, private-methods

Consider the following class

```
class Foo(object):

    @staticmethod
    def __is():
        print('__is')

    def m(self):
        Foo.__is()  # executes


Foo.__is()  # fails because of mangling

print(Foo.__dict__.keys())
```

`Foo.__is()` when it is run after the class is defined, it fails because of name mangaling. How is python interpreter able to resolve `Foo.__is()` inside methods but not outside the class?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1301369/183910

Comment: @BernhardVallant not a duplicate - the op clearly knows about the name-mangling mechanism, the question is "how is this implemented".

Comment: Note that your first two class statements raise an error because Foo is not yet defined. Used inside methods they work because methods body won't execute until called. And by then the class is already defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name mangling for names starting with `__` inside a class, is implemented by rewriting this names to the mangled form, inside the class ONLY. So your `Foo.__is` inside the class gets replaced by `_Foo__is` that is now present in the class `__dict__`. That attribute is accessible either inside or outside the class, so no private protection. But after replacement the `__is` name does not exist anywhere (I think), that's why it does not work from outside.

From the Python help:

> "__*"
>      Class-private names.  Names in this category, when used within the
>      context of a class definition, are re-written to use a mangled form
>      to help avoid name clashes between “private” attributes of base and
>      derived classes. See section Identifiers (Names).

Also see my comment to errors in your code snippet.

Comment: You are right. I was using ipython to test code and `Foo.__is()` inside class body was working because it was using previous `Foo` class not the current one.

Answer (score -2):

You can think of classes as of namespaces with some whistles.

One of whistles is ability to resolve `__methods` inside themselves without `_class__method`. This is no different from "magic" of automatically passing instances as first argument to methods (your regular `self`)

To illustrate "namespace" idea, you can do some weird things like

```
class A:
    def insane():
        return 42

    for _ in range(5):
        print(insane()
```

Comment: How does this answer the question ? The OP already knows what you posted, the question is "how is it actually implemented".